# PictureBox com cantos arredondados sem serrilhado?

Tags: winforms, vb.net

O que eu preciso fazer é uma `PictureBox` que tenha os cantos arredondados, mas o problema é que não consigo fazer eles ficarem redondos sem serrilhados.

Um dos jeitos que eu achei é fazer isso foi usando a propriedade `Region`:

```
 Private Function GetRoundedRect(ByVal retangulo As RectangleF, ByVal raio As Single) As GraphicsPath
    ' Se o raio do arco for maior ou igual à metada da largura ou altura do retângulo
    ' retorna um objeto no formato de capsula.
    If raio >= (Math.Min(retangulo.Width, retangulo.Height) / 2.0) Then
        Return GetCapsule(retangulo)
    End If

    Dim diametro As Single = raio + raio
    Dim arcRect As New RectangleF(retangulo.Location, New SizeF(diametro, diametro))
    Dim gp As New GraphicsPath()

    ' Arco superior esquerdo.
    gp.AddArc(arcRect, 180, 90)

    ' Arco superior direito.
    arcRect.X = retangulo.Right - diametro
    gp.AddArc(arcRect, 270, 90)

    ' Arco inferior direito.
    arcRect.Y = retangulo.Bottom - diametro
    gp.AddArc(arcRect, 0, 90)

    ' Arco inferior esquerdo
    arcRect.X = retangulo.Left
    gp.AddArc(arcRect, 90, 90)

    gp.CloseFigure()
    Return gp
End Function

Private Function GetCapsule(ByVal retangulo As RectangleF) As GraphicsPath
    Dim diametro As Single
    Dim arcRect As RectangleF
    Dim gp As New GraphicsPath()
    Try

        If retangulo.Width > retangulo.Height Then
            ' Capsula horizontal
            diametro = retangulo.Height
            arcRect = New RectangleF(retangulo.Location, New SizeF(diametro, diametro))
            gp.AddArc(arcRect, 90, 180)
            arcRect.X = retangulo.Right - diametro
            gp.AddArc(arcRect, 270, 180)
        ElseIf retangulo.Height > retangulo.Width Then
            ' Capsula horizontal
            diametro = retangulo.Width
            arcRect = New RectangleF(retangulo.Location, New SizeF(diametro, diametro))
            gp.AddArc(arcRect, 180, 180)
            arcRect.Y = retangulo.Bottom - diametro
            gp.AddArc(arcRect, 0, 180)
        Else
            ' Circulo
            gp.AddEllipse(retangulo)
        End If
    Catch e As Exception
        gp.AddEllipse(retangulo)
    Finally
        gp.CloseFigure()
    End Try

    Return gp
End Function
```

Como eu usei:

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)

    Me.Region = New System.Drawing.Region(GetRoundedRect(New RectangleF(0, 0, Width, Height), 20))

    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
End Sub
```

Isso funciona, mas gera cantos serrilhados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então eu pensei em fazer a mesma coisa usando o `Graphics`. O que eu tentei fazer foi delimitar a área onde a imagem iria aparecer deixando o resto com a cor de `Background` do controle onde a `Picturebox` estava.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    ' Qualidade
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
    e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear


    Dim Fonte As Bitmap = ImaList(0)

    Dim f As GraphicsPath = GetRoundedRect(New RectangleF(0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height), 20)
    Dim borderPen As New Pen(PictureBox1.Parent.BackColor, 1) With {
        .Alignment = PenAlignment.Outset
    }

    ' Cria limite para área do desenho
    e.Graphics.Clip = New Region(f)

    ' Desenha a imagem
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Fonte, 0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)

    'Aplica uma bordar para nao ficar serrilhado
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(borderPen, f)

End Sub
```

O resultado é bom, ele não fica mais com o serrilhado, mas ao tentar colocar uma `label` igual a imagem anterior ela fica igual está a parte de baixo da imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então o que eu queria saber é como posso deixar as bordas arredondadas sem serrilhado, levando em consideração os controles que estão dentro dela? Só lembrando que a `label` tem uma animação de subir e descer, então preciso que os eventos funcionem normalmente.

Answer (score -1):

Lucas Pedro, experimente usar o "AntiAlias". Seria algo assim:

```
 // Set the SmoothingMode property to smooth the line.
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = 
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```

Veja também:

[Graphics.SmoothingMode Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode?view=netframework-4.8)

[Antialiasing for Drawing2D.GraphicsPath](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?792045-Antialiasing-for-Drawing2D-GraphicsPath)

[How to make smooth round ellipse form?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c7faa198-2c95-4990-8dd9-806efd941480/how-to-make-smooth-round-ellipse-form?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: `SmoothingMode` não funciona se usar o `Region`, quando adiciono um controle filho fica serrilhado. Os outros 2 dão bons resultados, mas ainda tenho o problema de quando adiciono um controle filho, ele sempre fica em cima das bordas redondas. Eu resolvi esse problema pintando o controle filho, mas não consigo adicionar as "bordas" no controle filho (quando adiciono por exemplo uma linha preta em volta do controle pai eu não consigo desenhar no controle filho, para ficar igual ao pai, já que eu não consegui deixar a "pintura" por cima do do controle filho.